# Autofac in OWIN, WebAPI & WebForms - single mixed application

Tags: autofac

There are separate guides for how to do Autofac for each one of these, but I have them all in a single (quite massive) application.

What is the proper way to do it then? 
Application_Start vs. Owin Startup.cs etc.